# javascript prototype inheritance again

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I'm not new to Javascript programming, but I can't understand it's prototype objects, inheritance whatever. As I'm trying to work though this stuff, what questions do I need to ask the code to figure this thing out.

Comment: If you have any questions, just ask. Asking a question about asking questions won't be very helpful.

Comment: This site is set up so that you can ask a question and we can answer it so that someone doesn't have to in the future. Stack Overflow requires that you actually ask a clear question that can be reasonably answered and will be useful in the future. Best of luck with understanding prototypes, they are a bit evil :)

Comment: if I have an object with a prototype and a method how do I run the method on the property: obj.prop.method()

Comment: I was trying to ask how to think through prototype inheritance in javascript. I never have groked it, have spent an embarressing amount of time trying to understand. As an analogy, it's hard to look up in a dictionary (dead tree edition) how to spell a word, if you don't know how to spell it well enough to look it up.

Comment: Thanks Greg Ross, Norguard. I'll reread both and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Using "class-based" object creation in JavaScript:

```
var Wallet = function (pin, starting_balance, overdraft) {
    this.amount = starting_balance;
    this.pin = pin;
    this.overdraft = overdraft;
};


Wallet.prototype.addFunds = function (amount) {
    this.amound += amount;
};

Wallet.prototype.withdrawFunds = function (amount) {
    if (this.amount + this.overdraft >= amount) {
        this.amount -= amount;
        return new Wallet(this.pin, amount, this.overdraft);
    }
};

Wallet.prototype.displayBalance = function () {
    var cents = this.amount % 100,
        dollars = (this.amount - cents) / 100,
        total = dollars + "." + (cents > 9 ? cents : ("0" + cents));

    var output = "Current Balance: $" + total;
};



var myWallet = new Wallet(1234, 2000, 100000);
myWallet.displayBalance(); // "Current Balance: $20.00"
```

By using the `new` operator on a `constructor` function, which returns `this`, I can modify the `prototype` of the constructor function.

ie: modifying `Wallet.prototype`.

Then, all `Wallet`s have the same functionality.

Of course, this isn't a very safe wallet.  Anybody in the world could come along and change `myWallet.amount` or `myWallet.pin`.

But if I make the wallet safer:

```
var Wallet = function (pin, amount, overdraft) {
    var balance = amount,
        keyCode = pin,
        padding = overdraft;
};

Wallet.prototype.depositFunds = function (amount) { balance += amount; }; // does NOT work
```

This won't work.  Prototypes can ***ONLY ACCESS PUBLIC PROPERTIES OF THE OBJECT RETURNED BY THE CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION***

Meaning that `Obj.prototype.<whatever>` will only be able to access things which are added to the object through `this.<whatever> = <x>;` in the constructor, or after the fact, when you manually add something `myObj.property = <x>;`.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post, [Understanding JavaScript Prototypes](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/), really helped me understand it all.

Methods defined by the prototype of an object can be called directly on the object. For example if obj has a prototype that has a method called 'doSomething' then we can call `obj.doSomething()`.